# Nginx proxy and remove proxy_pass prefix

Tags: nginx, proxy

i want use nginx location proxy my applications

```
nginx(ip address) : 10.255.1.10
php(10.255.1.20)
```

Ip access:

```
10.255.1.20/            "access ok(200)"
10.255.1.20/api        "access ok(200)"
10.255.1.20/project    "access ok(200)"
```

but i use nginx proxy access 404

```
example.com/work      "access ok(200)"
example.com/work/api  "access not found(404)"
example.com/work/project  "access not found(404)"
```

Nginx ConfigFile:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /work/ {
        proxy_pass              http://10.255.8.77:8065/;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        HOST $host/work;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
  }
```

i want this:

```
"curl http://example.com/work          200"
"curl http://example.com/work/api      200"
"curl http://example.com/work/project  200"
```

thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The trailing slash does this magic, take it out from proxy_pass and it should help:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /work/ {
        proxy_pass              http://10.255.8.77:8065;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        HOST $host/work;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
    }
  }
```

Let's see through the docs:

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

```
location /name/ {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
}
```

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server **in the same**
>   **form as sent by a client** when the original request is processed, or
>   the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed
>   URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1; 
}
```

Comment: @anatoly Thanx for a concise, easily readable and well documented answer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you actually want clients to be able to request the resource with an optional trailing slash. e.g. `/work` or `/work/`

Comment: @david for calls without trailing slash - redirect with: 
location = /work {
  return 302 /work/;
}